# Trying to randomly select an class from an array and apply to body (JS NOOB)

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, fonts, colors

Trying to randomly select on of the color classes once the color span is clicked then apply it to the body, not sure how to randomize or use `math.random()` on the array selection and apply a new colored theme per each click.

```js
// Select the element
var body = document.querySelector('body');

// Array of color Classes
var classColorArray = ['tan-red', 'orange-green', 'deep-green-orange'];

// Apply the new classes
var cl = body.classList;

document.querySelector('span.reverse').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  body.className = ''; // Clear
  cl.add('reverse'); // Add
});
document.querySelector('span.default').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  body.className = ''; // Clear
});
document.querySelector('span.color').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  body.className = ''; // Clear
  cl.add.apply(cl, classColorArray);
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: helvetica;
}

.color-selector {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.color-selector span {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.color-selector span.reverse {
  background: #080808;
}

.color-selector span.default {
  border: 1px solid #080808;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.color-selector span.color {
  background: rgb(0, 16, 255);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 16, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 29, 29, 1) 50%, rgba(230, 242, 77, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 16, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 29, 29, 1) 50%, rgba(230, 242, 77, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 16, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 29, 29, 1) 50%, rgba(230, 242, 77, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#0010ff", endColorstr="#e6f24d", GradientType=1);
}

.color-selector span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

body.tan-red {
  color: rgb(239, 232, 216);
  background-color: rgb(255, 69, 82);
}

body.orange-green {
  color: rgb(255, 81, 0);
  background-color: rgb(179, 225, 41);
}

body.deep-green-orange {
  background-color: rgb(252, 108, 17);
  color: rgb(30, 59, 52);
}

body.reverse {
  color: #FFFDFA;
  background: #080808;
}

body.reverse .color-selector span.reverse {
  border: 1px solid #FFFDFA;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body.reverse .color-selector span.default {
  background: #FFFDFA;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="color-selector">
    <span class="default"></span>
    <span class="reverse"></span>
    <span class="color"></span>
  </div>
  <h1>Testing This Thing</h1>
  <p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet</p>
</body>
```

Trying to randomly select on of the color classes once the color span is clicked then apply it to the body, not sure how to randomize the array selection and apply per click.

Test site located here:
http://alexcoven.com/type/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Select the element
    var body = document.querySelector('body');

    // Array of color Classes
    var classColorArray = ['tan-red', 'orange-green', 'deep-green-orange'];

    // Apply the new classes
    var cl = body.classList;

    document.querySelector('span.reverse').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        body.className = ''; // Clear
        cl.add('reverse'); // Add
          event.preventDefault();
    });
    document.querySelector('span.default').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        body.className = ''; // Clear
          event.preventDefault();
    });
    document.querySelector('span.color').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        body.className = ''; // Clear
        cl.add.apply(cl, classColorArray);
          event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is a bit of a mess. First, always include all the relevant code so we can reproduce your issue and provide a working answer. In this case, that means editing your question and including the relevant HTML and CSS. When you do edit the question, enter the code in a Stack Snippet (the <> button on the edit toolbar), which will allow us to run the code right here. Please don't expect us to go out to a 3rd party site to test your work and 3rd party links can die over time, making your question here un-testable in the future.

Comment: Now, to your code, there is no reason to add `event.preventDefault()` on the `click` event of a `span` since there is no default `click` behavior of a `span`. Also, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish by calling `apply` on the `classList.add()` method. Finally, your question asks about a random class, but there's no code in your question that attempts to use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

Comment: Also, regarding the `event.preventDefault()` : you're not passing `event`, you're passing `e`.  So `event` is not defined.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for the heads up, Added the snippet here for the community as for the ```event.preventDefaults()``` I went ahead and removed those as well. Not sure how to apply the ```Math.random()``` function in my setup tbh that's kind what I was hoping someone would help me figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key concepts to solving this are:

- [Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)
- [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)
- [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
- The [`.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

See the comments inline below for how to make this work.

```js
// Select the body element
var body = document.querySelector('body');

// Array of color Classes
var classColorArray = ['tan-red', 'orange-green', 'deep-green-orange'];

// Just set up one event handler at the document level.
// Any clicks within the document will trigger events
// that "bubble" up the DOM and be handled here.
// This is a better approach than setting up 3 event handlers
// that all basically do the same thing.
document.addEventListener("click", e => {

  // Check to see if the event was triggered by one of the spans
  // that we care about. Instead of each span having a different
  // class, they all that the same one, so we'll know which ones
  // we care about. The event (e) in this case .target is a 
  // reference to the element that originated the event.
  if(e.target.classList.contains("colorSpan")){
  
    // We generate a random between 0 and 1 (exclusive) with Math.random()
    // then we multiply that by the length of the array to get a number that 
    // is between 0 and the highest index used in the array. The we 
    // round that down to the nearest whole number with Math.floor()
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * classColorArray.length);
    
    // Keep looping as long as the random is the same as what's already in use
    while(body.classList.contains(classColorArray[random])){
      // Random in use already, pick another random and check again
      random = Math.floor(Math.random() * classColorArray.length);
    }
    // Finally have a new color
    // Clear the current styles from the body
    body.classList = "";
    body.classList.add(classColorArray[random]);
  }
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: helvetica;
}

.color-selector {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.color-selector span {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.color-selector span.reverse {
  background: #080808;
}

.color-selector span.default {
  border: 1px solid #080808;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.color-selector span.color {
  background: rgb(0, 16, 255);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 16, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 29, 29, 1) 50%, rgba(230, 242, 77, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 16, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 29, 29, 1) 50%, rgba(230, 242, 77, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 16, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 29, 29, 1) 50%, rgba(230, 242, 77, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#0010ff", endColorstr="#e6f24d", GradientType=1);
}

.color-selector span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

body.tan-red {
  color: rgb(239, 232, 216);
  background-color: rgb(255, 69, 82);
}

body.orange-green {
  color: rgb(255, 81, 0);
  background-color: rgb(179, 225, 41);
}

body.deep-green-orange {
  background-color: rgb(252, 108, 17);
  color: rgb(30, 59, 52);
}

body.reverse {
  color: #FFFDFA;
  background: #080808;
}

body.reverse .color-selector span.reverse {
  border: 1px solid #FFFDFA;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body.reverse .color-selector span.default {
  background: #FFFDFA;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="color-selector">
    <span class="colorSpan">a</span>
    <span class="colorSpan">b</span>
    <span class="colorSpan">c</span>
  </div>
  <h1>Testing This Thing</h1>
  <p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet</p>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks man! Really appreciate the help here. Is there a way to make sure the same item doesn't get selected twice?

Comment: @alcoven Yes, just generate the new random before wiping out the `classList` and check to see if `body.classList.contains(reference to the new random here)`. If so, generate a new random.

Comment: How do I call the "refrence to the new random"? sorry super noob at JS here

Comment: Instead of generating the random at the moment you want to pass it into the array, generate it first thing and assign the answer to a variable, as in `let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * classColorArray.length);`. Then, you can use that variable in the "reference to the new random here" spot and in between the `[]`.

Comment: Would I need to add it into an if statement or something? IF ```body.classList.contains([random]);``` then ```cl.add(classColorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * classColorArray.length)]);```

Comment: @alcoven I have updated the answer to address your last question(s).

Comment: Thanks man! I've updated on my end and everything is working smooth. If you goto https://alexcoven.com/type/ you can see it and test it out. Not sure why it's not working on mobile but the desktop version is working great!